Issue with Mentions and Hashtags via LinkedIn API
We’re investigating a problem with the LinkedIn API where mentions and hashtags are not recognized when posting via the API. We’ve thoroughly reviewed the LinkedIn documentation and even attempted a hardcoded test using LinkedIn's example organization.
Here are the details:
According to the LinkedIn documentation, a valid post should be structured like this:
{
  "author": "urn:li:organization:123456789",
  "commentary": "Hello @[Devtestco](urn:li:organization:2414183)",
  "visibility": "PUBLIC",
  "distribution": {
      "feedDistribution": "MAIN_FEED",
      "targetEntities": [],
      "thirdPartyDistributionChannels": []
  },
  "lifecycleState": "PUBLISHED",
  "isReshareDisabledByAuthor": false
}

Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/community-management/shares/posts-api?view=li-lms-2024-10&tabs=http#content
Our generated code follows this format:
#...
payload = {
  "author": f"urn:li:person:{user_id}",
  "commentary": text,
  "visibility": "PUBLIC",
  "distribution": {
    "feedDistribution": "MAIN_FEED",
    "targetEntities": [],
    "thirdPartyDistributionChannels": [],
  },
  "content": {
    "media": {
      "altText": credential_name,
      "id": thumbnail_urn,
    }
  },
  "lifecycleState": "PUBLISHED",
  "isReshareDisabledByAuthor": False
}
response = requests.post("https://api.linkedin.com/rest/posts", data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers)
#...

And the variable text is generated so:
f"{text}\n @[Devtestco](urn:li:organization:2414183) {hashtags}\n{credential_link}"

The API version we call is 202407, but even with version 202410 the problem staies.
We used "Devtestco" as a placeholder for testing, but the output looks like this:

The API does not seem to parse the commentary correctly, as mentions and hashtags only work if manually added after the post has been created.
How to resolve this, or apply some workaround?
What we already did: Check code and documentation multiple times. Google and search on stackoverflow without a finding.
